# Python Amazon Simple Product API: 400 Bad Request

Tags: python, api, amazon-product-api

So I read a couple of posts already regarding this topic and tried some things they mentioned to do to no avail. I am fairly certain I have correctly given my account permission to API calls, but that wasn't the problem. I saw something about signing a request to an AWS search, but I'm not quite sure if that's it or how I would even do it.

This is the code I have.

```
from amazon.api import AmazonAPI

def get_amazon_link(item):
    amazon = AmazonAPI('...AmazonKey', '...SecretKey', '...AssociateTag')
    try:
        product = amazon.lookup(ItemId='B00GDQ0RMG')
    except Exception as e:
        print e
    print product
```

Right now the item I'm passing the function is hard coded just to try and get it working. If anyone could help me out that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you pass the correct region for which your account is registered. More info [here](https://github.com/yoavaviram/python-amazon-simple-product-api/issues/95).